# get text from textarea and copy it in input onclick button

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm using ASP MVC 4 Razor , I want to get text from a textarea and copy it in an input when click on button.

here is my code view

```
<textarea  name="resultSearch" id="resultSearch" rows="10" class="form-control">
    @if (ViewBag.highlightedText != null) { 
        foreach (var person in ViewBag.highlightedText) {
            @person
        } 
    }
</textarea>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok thanks , I didn't know it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm not misunderstanding the question you just need to write a little JavaScript.  You need to make sure that your `textarea`, `button`, and `input` both have an `id` attribute.  Let's assume the following:

- `textarea: resultSearch`
- `button: myButton`
- `input: myInput`

With those assumptions you might write the following JavaScript (jQuery is required):

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#myInput').val($('#resultSearch').val());
});
```